# How to show a set of images in Google SERP?

Tags: seo, google-search, images, products

If I search for the keyword "urne cinerarie" (that is "cinerary urns") in my country (Italy) the search results show me a list of sites. In addition to title and description, for some sites Google also shows a set of images. How can I achieve a similar result for my website?

[image: google search results with product images]

Answer (score 2):

So far, no one has figured out what exactly is the cause. Every study and article I have read came to similar conclusions:

- Mostly available for category pages or product-listing-pages. Basically, pages where picking an image is part of the user journey/navigational flow.
- Shown both for pages with and without schema
- You need a lot of images, ideally in different formats (landscape and portrait)